# howto read gemalto rfid card using smart card reader on universal windows platform

Tags: uwp

Hi I want to read gemalto rfid card through smart card reader using **universal windows platform** with c#, though i have tested it in wpf and windows application it's working perfectly using **winscard.dll**.

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, you could use the [Windows.Devices.SmartCards API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.SmartCards) to work with smart cards.

You could check the official [Smart cards sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmartCard) to learn how to use these APIs.